# TextView's on the same line, selecting one cancels the other

Tags: android, select, colors, click, textview

I'm new to Android.
I have a list of LinearLayouts; each list has 3 TextView's, 2 clickable TextViews 'Da' and 'Nu' and one only for the Text.
If i click on the 'Da' textview it will turn Green and if i click on the 'Nu' it will turn Red.
My problem is that if I want to select 'Da' on a line, then select 'Nu', the Green one should return to the standard color (how it was before the selection) so I can select only 1 TextView per line.

```
    public ProgramAZView(Context context, String name) {
    super(context);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater =  LayoutInflater.from(context);
    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.program_az_view, this);



    Da = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dreaptaDA);
    Da.setOnClickListener(new TextView.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
                Da.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Green);
        }
    });


    Nu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stangaNU);
    Nu.setOnClickListener(new TextView.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
                Nu.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Red);
        }
    });

    pazName = name;
    SetName(name);
}
```

Comment: Didnt get you. what you wanna to do??? clear your answers

Comment: I want to make those two TextViews same like radio buttons, if i select one the other deselects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try!

```
Da = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dreaptaDA);
Drawable DAoriginalBackground = Da.getBackground();
Nu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stangaNU);
Drawable NUoriginalBackground = Nu.getBackground();

Da.setOnClickListener(new TextView.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
            Da.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Green);
            Nu.setBackgroundResource(NUoriginalBackground);
    }
});

Nu.setOnClickListener(new TextView.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
            Nu.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Red);
            Da.setBackgroundResource(DAoriginalBackground);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use txt_view.setClickable(false);

Comment: I cannot imagine how that should help.

Comment: set it in onClickListener by runtime.

Comment: But how does it reset the bg color of the previously selected view?